# How do I show that $E\equiv \frac12 m \dot{x}^2 + U(x)$ is constant for a classical particle moving under the action of $F(x) = -dU/dx$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

> A mass $m$ moves in one dimension $x$ under the action of a (net) force $F(x)$. The force can be derived from a function $U(x)$ according to the formula
>   $$
> F(x) = -dU/dx.
> $$
>   Show that the quantity
>   $$
> E\equiv \frac12 m \dot{x}^2 + U(x)
> $$
>   is a constant of motion.

How do I show that E is constant. any help?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Hint: if something is constant then it isn't changing over time. What does this mean for the time derivative of $E$?

Comment: Also: please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 2):

A force that can be expressed in terms of a potential $V$ is referred to as *conservative*, exaclty because it conserves energy.

Consider the total mechanical energy $E$, being the sum of a potential energy $V(\mathbf{x})$ and kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}m\left ( \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}^2 \right )$:

$$ E = \frac{1}{2}m\left ( \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}^2 \right ) + V(\mathbf{x}),$$ which is termed *mechanical energy*.

For this to be **conserved**, i.e. a **constant** in time, then its total time derivative must vanish:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0, $$

where by the chain rule:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t} =  \sum_{k=x,y,z} \left [ m\frac{\mathrm{d}x_k}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_k}\frac{\mathrm{d}x_k}{\mathrm{d}t} \right ] =  \sum_{k=x,y,z} \left ( m\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_k}\right )\frac{\mathrm{d}x_k}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0.$$

You recognise the first term $ m\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2}  $ as the expression for the force $F_k$ in Newton's second law.

The equality is satisfied only if $m\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2}   = F_k = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_k}$, meaning $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla V$. 
 In such a case, the force would be called a *conservative force*.

There are a lot of equivalent definitions for a conservative force, all which stem from the essential one: a conservative force is any force that can be written as the gradient of a potential $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla V$.

- By the rules of vector calculus, $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} \propto \nabla \times \nabla V = 0$, so any conservative force field has no vorticity, $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = 0$.
- By Stokes's theorem, the above constraint can be made into a path integral one: $\iint \nabla \times \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S} = \oint \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} = 0$ for *any* path, since the left hand side is *always* zero, regardless of the surface $\mathbf{S}$. So any conservative force is path independent.